Better Methods to Find a Point's Coordinates with Three Collinear Points
Question:
If three points A(a,2), B(3,7), and C(-2,-9a) lie on the same straight line, what is the value of the real number a?
My method is as follows:
"Calculate the value of a by solving the equation when the slopes of the lines formed by pairing these three points are equal.
Clear["`*"]
A = {a, 2}; B = {3, 7}; C1 = {-2, -9 a};
Equal @@ 
  MapThread[((#1[[2]] - #2[[2]])/(#1[[1]] - #2[[1]])) &, 
   Subsets[{A, B, C1}, {2}][[{1, -1}]]] // Reduce[#, a, Reals] &


Better defined:

How can I modify the code I wrote to achieve a smarter purpose? I manually entered the code Subsets[{A, B, C1}, {2}][[{1, -1}]], which causes a situation where the slope does not exist; is there a way to filter this operation?



Is there a more concise form and method for the code?

Is there a built-in function that could solve this problem?



-1. (1) After asking 310 undeleted questions, you still refuse to search in document or this site before asking a question. (2) The line "How can I modify the code I wrote to achieve a smarter purpose? I manually entered the code Subsets[{A, B, C1}, {2}][[{1, -1}]], which causes a situation where the slope does not exist; is there a way to filter this operation?" is just chaotic. I don't see your effort in asking a clear question.

@xzczd Firstly, I understand your dissatisfaction with the way I ask questions, but each of my questions is based on my attempts to solve the problem myself. Regarding searching through documentation and websites, I have indeed made efforts to do so. However, sometimes I still encounter problems that are difficult to solve on my own or find alternative solutions that might broaden my perspective and thinking, which is why I turn to the community for help.

As for the specific issue mentioned, I believe it was quite clear. I was discussing how to improve the code Subsets[{A, B, C1}, {2}][[{1, -1}]] to avoid situations where the slope is undefined, that is, how to automatically select lists that meet the slope conditions without manually entering the specific list.


Then why don't you find CollinearPoints? How do you search? 2. "As for the specific issue mentioned, I believe it was quite clear. "Are you serious?: https://i.sstatic.net/GsxFDLhQ.png 3. Those words "smarter purpose", "I manually entered", etc. are also confusing. Of course it's understandable for those (like me) who have read tons of bad questions, and usually I'm not that picky on language competence, but having read almost all of your questions, I know pretty well you can write much better English texts (just like your last comments making excuse), you're just careless.


@xzczd The parameter difference in the picture indicates that this parameter needs to be manually input and eliminates the cases where the slope of two points in the obtained list does not exist. The intelligent requirement is to automatically select the corresponding combination from three points to make the slope exist and calculate the coordinates of the points.


What you wrote is "I manually entered the code Subsets[{A, B, C1}, {2}][[{1, -1}]], which causes a situation where the slope does not exist" 2. I repeat: why don't you find CollinearPoints? How do you search?


Why not search the documentation center for "collinear points" first?:
CollinearPoints[{{a, 2}, {3, 7}, {-2, -9 a}}] // Solve


Perhaps
area=Cross[ A - B ] . (C1 - B)/2;(* area of triangle *)
Solve[0 == area, a]
(* {{a -> 2/9}, {a -> 2}} *)

or
Solve[0 == A - B - t (C1 - B), {t, a}]
(* {{t -> 1/5, a -> 2}, {t -> 5/9, a -> 2/9}} *)

Hope it helps!

That's a good idea! Also:  A = {a, 2}; B = {3, 7}; C1 = {-2, -9 a}; Area[Triangle[{A, B, C1}]] == 0 // Reduce[#, a] &

@csn899 Clever to add // Reduce[#, a] &

Or RegionEqual for two lines.
A = {a, 2}; B = {3, 7}; C1 = {-2, -9 a};
RegionEqual[InfiniteLine[{B, A}], InfiniteLine[{B, C1}]] // Solve


{{a -> 2/9}, {a -> 2}}


You can try
u = {a, 2};
v = {3, 7};
t = {-2, -9 a};
Solve[u - v == k (u - t)]


{{a -> 2/9, k -> -(5/4)}, {a -> 2, k -> -(1/4)}}

or
Solve[Det[{u - v, u - t}] == 0, a]


{{a -> 2/9}, {a -> 2}}

You can also try
u = {a, 2, 0};
v = {3, 7, 0};
t = {-2, -9 a, 0};
Solve[Cross[u - v, u - t] == 0, a]


{{a -> 2/9}, {a -> 2}}


We can divide the changes by the step sizes to get the slopes, and then find where the 2 slopes are equal:
pts = {{a, 2}, {3, 7}, {-2, -9 a}};

Reduce[Equal @@ Divide @@@ Differences@pts, a]
(*a == 2/9 || a == 2*)


I guess I am the idiot here, but it is simple: A+(B-A)*x=C This means you have two variables: x and a and two equations. x=-(2+a)/(3-a) = -(9a+2)/5 and this becomes a quadratic equation, which is simple to solve answers: a=2/9 and 2.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! This site is not about mathematics per se, but about programming in Wolfram Languagw and Wolfram Mathematica. That is why all answers generally require some code, while you are only giving a mathematical procedure.

Determine the coordinate values using the condition that the slopes between the middle pairs of three points are equal.
A = {a, 2}; B = {3, 7}; C1 = {-2, -9 a};
Equal @@ (((A[[2]] - #[[2]])/(A[[1]] - #[[1]])) & /@ {B, C1}) // 
 Reduce[#, a, Reals] &

A = {a, 2}; B = {3, 7}; C1 = {-2, -9 a};
Equal @@ 
  MapThread[((#1[[2]] - #2[[2]])/(#1[[1]] - #2[[1]])) &, 
   Select[Subsets[Subsets[{A, B, C1}, {2}], {2}], 
     UnsameQ @@ #[[All, 1]] && UnsameQ @@ #[[All, 2]] &] // 
    Flatten[#, 1] &] // Reduce[#, a, Reals] &

Or
Clear["`*"]
A = {a, 2}; B = {3, 7}; C1 = {-2, -9 a};
Equal @@ 
  MapThread[((#1[[2]] - #2[[2]])/(#1[[1]] - #2[[1]])) &, 
   First@Gather[
     Union@Flatten[Subsets[Subsets[{A, B, C1}, {2}], {2}], 
       1], #1[[1]] =!= #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] =!= #2[[2]] &]] // 
 Reduce[#, a, Reals] &


(–1) How is this more concise and better than your initial code?

@Domen This answer should not have -1. Although the code seems cumbersome, it solves the problem of manually selecting a list and meets the first requirement.

@csn899 As mentioned in comment under your question, currently your "first requirement" is a mess and only understandable for those can guess out what you mean, so your answer definitely deserves downvotes.
